# Search and replace in *.aspx,*.ascx files when publishing a Webapplication

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, post-build-event, pre-build-event

I'm attempting to replace a pattern in all my .aspx and .ascx file when I Publish my Webapplication.

When I am running the application locally, I don't care about the replace. But as soon as I need to Publish the solution I need a sequence of characters, let's say "ABC", replaced with "DEF" in all my .aspx and .ascx files.

How would I go about performing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a separate script, that goes through your folder searching and loading all your .aspx and .ascx files, open them and replace all the needed stuff. I don't know how to do it in asp, but in actionscript it would look like `fileText = fileText.replace(/ABC/g,"DEF");`

Answer (score 0):

`perl -p -i -e 's/ABC/EDF/g'  *.aspx`

`perl -p -i -e 's/ABC/EDF/g'  *.ascx`

Comment: It's not that I don't think that this would work, but Perl isn't quite what I'm looking for in conjunction with Visual Studio 2008.